# Why did Spinoza believe that God's infinity, but not God's perfection, implied causal necessity?

Tags: causation, spinoza

<sub>Source: p 121, *Philosophy: A Complete Introduction* (2012) by [Prof Sharon Kaye (MA PhD (Philosophy), U. Toronto)](http://sites.jcu.edu/philosophy/professor/sharon-kaye/)</sub>

> 6. For Spinoza, causal necessity is implied by which of the 
>   following?
>
> a) God's infinity
>
> b) God's perfection
>
> c) Human imagination
>
> d) The constant conjunction of events

On page 219, the answer key states that the answer is (a), but why is (b) incorrect?

Page 114 summarizes Spinoza's view that God's infinity implies that God is everything. But how can God be infinite (in his omnibenevolence,  omnipotence, omniscience) if God is not perfect?

Answer (score 1):

As these Propositions clearly demonstrate, god's 'perfection' and 'infinity' are inseparable and conjointly 'produce' causal necessity.

Prop. 21- “All things which follow from the absolute nature of any attribute of god must always exist and be infinite, or, in other words, are eternal and infinite through the said attribute.”
Prop. 22- “Whatsoever follows from any attribute of god, in so far as it is modified by a modification, which exists necessarily and is infinite, through the said attribute, must also exist necessarily and be eternal.”
Prop. 23- “Every mode which exists both necessarily and as infinite, must necessarily follow either from the absolute nature of some attribute of god, or from an attribute modified by a modification which exists necessarily, and as infinite.” [Page- 19,Ethics Part 1- Concerning God, (Elwes Translation)

@Greek-Area51Proposal
Regards, Charles M Saunders